# React Native - Manipulate array when object have same id

Tags: arrays, react-native

I have an array named `ticketCart` and it store ticket that users add, if I have an objects that looks something like this with same id on it, how can I distinguish with other objects that have a same id?

```
ADDEDKEY Array [
  Object {
    "desc": "tunjukkan tiket saat masuk",
    "idTicket": "47",
    "name": "vip",
    "price": "70000",
    "quota": "1459",
    "status": "Available",
    "type": "PAID",
    "value": 2,
  },
  Object {
    "desc": "tunjukkan tiket saat masuk",
    "idTicket": "47",
    "name": "vip",
    "price": "70000",
    "quota": "1459",
    "status": "Available",
    "type": "PAID",
    "value": 2,
  },
]
```

I tried to do something like `forEach` on it but it doesn't work, id (`number`) is still the same (In here, I'm using `number` as an id)

```
ticketCart.forEach((o, key) => {
  ticketCart[key].number = key + 1;
})
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `item`? What is `no`? You need to provide more information on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli sorry typo on there, already fixed now

Comment: I think you can handle this with `set` in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by distinguish? What are you trying to achieve?

For example, you could identify each object by it's index in the array:

```
for (let i = 0; i < ticketCart.length; i++) {
  ticketCart[i].number = ticketCart[i].id + "_" + i;
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is the system can detect the difference between these 2 objects in `ticketCart` because what I do on the post above is when user add 2 ticket with same id, there will be a trouble